# Spark Streaming: how to propagate updates to a Broadcast variable to the whole cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a module in the Spark driver listening to a Kafka Queue and depending on the content of the Queue I need to modify the content of a Broadcast variable (or a closure). In this example this could be a String.

For example if the string "change" arrives on the queue, I need to update the Broadcast variable in every node.

I would like to see a pattern to do this that is clean and performant or at least receive an input on where I can find some material to better understand how to propagate modifications in the Spark Cluster.

Comment: Could you some sample code to illustrate what you want to do?

Comment: In particular, "I have a module in the Spark driver listening to a Kafka Queue"  is puzzling. See discussion on @Bacon answer for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast variable are indeed propagating variables or whole closures to the spark cluster, using a peer to peer protocol.

From the [Learning Spark book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do):

> A broadcast variable is
>   simply an object of type spark.broadcast.Broadcast[T], which wraps a value of
>   type T. We can access this value by calling value on the Broadcast object in our
>   tasks. The value is sent to each node only once, using an efficient, BitTorrent-like
>   communication mechanism.

What will impact on performance is the serialization method you're using (e.g: Kryo, a custom one, ...):

There is an example in the book:

> Example 6-8. Country lookup with Broadcast values in Scala

```
// Look up the countries for each call sign for the
// contactCounts RDD. We load an array of call sign
// prefixes to country code to support this lookup.

val signPrefixes = sc.broadcast(loadCallSignTable())

val countryContactCounts = contactCounts.map {
    case (sign, count) =>
        val country = lookupInArray(sign, signPrefixes.value) (country, count)
    }.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)

countryContactCounts.saveAsTextFile(outputDir + "/countries.txt")
```

> As shown in these examples, the process of using broadcast variables is simple:
>   1. Create a Broadcast[T] by calling SparkContext.broadcast on an object of type
>   T. Any type works as long as it is also Serializable.
>   2. Access its value with the value property (or value() method in Java).
>   3. The variable will be sent to each node only once, and should be treated as read-
>   only (updates will not be propagated to other nodes).

Comment: "Broadcast variable are indeed propagating variables or whole closures to the spark cluster, using a peer to peer protocol."

Ok, this is something I was not sure about. I will try it in a snippet and see how it behaves. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK broadcast variables can only be declared on the driver (as the examples show) and if the requirement is to update some value based on something that was received at the one executor, this method will not work.

Comment: The OP wants to broadcast to the executors a value which is received on the driver.

Comment: @Bacon for me, that's not clear on the question. Given "For example if the string "change" arrives on the queue, I need to update the Broadcast variable in every node."  -- data arrives to the executors. Only a `collect()`  (or similar) would bring this to the driver, which may or may not be and option.

Comment: The OP states that the driver is listening to a Kafka queue, and that those messages should be forwarded on the executors.

Comment: @Bacon, well, that has to be something custom b/c Spark Streaming does not have such construction - I asked some sample code to sort that out.

Comment: Actually I made it work. I will eventually reply to my own question if I can refine the solution enough.

Comment: @Chobeat did you manage to achieve this without resorting to broadcast in every batch?

Comment: @ssedano not yet, we will resume working on it soon.